# Escaping spaces in variable while passing as a command line argument in php

Tags: php

I have a php file say **abc.php**, this is processing some command line arguments and at the end calling another php say **def.php**,

```
system("php /user/release/scheduler_test/def.php $name $final > ~/scheduler_test/logs/logs_$name.txt 2>&1 &")
```

The problem here is, the variable **$final** is having a huge string separated with spaces and since for php the space is the delimiter, it is not taking the entire **$final** as one argument.

I want to pass the value inside this **$final** variable as a single value. Can anyone tell me how? I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is why [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) is for. This does the escaping what you are exactly looking for.

A clearcut example from the PHP Docs..

```
<?php
system('ls '.escapeshellarg($dir));
?>
```

So escape your parameters/user-provided parameters using this function by wrapping this around it.